# Xml deserializing with meta datas

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I want to deserialize this Xml :

```
<Content id="1">
  <Element key="Description">Bla  bla bla</Element>
  <Element key="Title">The title</Element>  
</Content>
```

into this classes :

```
public class Content
{
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
        public string Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "description")]
        public string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
[XmlAttribute(XmlElement = "title")]
        public string Title
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
}
```

My problem is that i don't know how i can put the text of the right attribute in the class property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a helper class for the `<element>` XML node.

Another option would be to implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface:

```
public class Content: IXmlSerializable
{
    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        // write element nodes
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        // read element nodes
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking this too.  I'm hoping someone else has a better answer.  It would be nice to have a more flexible option.